# Anyone used the Izotope ANR-B Noise Reduction unit?

Tags: izotope, hardware, noise-reduction

Apparently it's very good, and in some studios it's the first choice to go to for ambient noise reduction, and the CEDAR is second...

Has anyone used one? Care to advise as to it's quality?

http://www.rspe.com/iZotope-ANR-B-Adaptive-Realtime-Noise-Reduction-Hardware/vmj_estore.tpl.html

http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/anrb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have Two izotope units we also have 3 cedar dns1500. The Izotope are built well and I prefer them over the cedars. Izo's work better at noise like skype feed stuff. Very transparent and really work like the plugins. The cedar does have more control having a low mid and high band. Where as the izo just has adaptive button with threshold and reduction u kinda rely on the izo to do what it needs to do and it does a very good job.  @utopia

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! So, if you had a choice to get only one or the other, for post production on interview videos where there is a lot of ambient noise (traffic wash, hiss, sometimes waterfalls, just regular ambient noise), would you choose the CEDAR or Izotope?

Comment: I would just buy the izotope plugins, unless you need live for broadcast feeds which you would want the hardware unit and or you do not have a dedicated audio workstation.  @utopia

Answer (score 1):

This is a standalone hardware unit, I guess this is for live or broadcast use, why not using the offline iZotope RX Advanced which is a great and surgical precision and far more accurate on handling and tweaking. Also comes with many  more tools and a great user interface.

@Utopia Are you in need of real time processing on your audio clean-up chain?

Comment: Thanks. I am basically looking to see if there is a comparable unit out there which might be better than the CEDAR for a new studio. But, so far it's been hard to beat their hardware unit. I haven't tried the Izotope hardware unit yet, but I hear it's great. Was wondering if anyone has used it. Thanks for the info!